# Problems with requiring various modules in react project

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, require, ace-editor

I have problems resolving the path to this module. Deleting and reinstalling node_modules sadly does not help.

Specifically i have problems using the `ace` Editor. It worked before but something went haywire...

[image]

As you can see other imports dont work either:

[image]

I am importing ace like so : `var ace = require('ace/ace');` after setting the pathing accordingly:

my folder structure looks like this:

[image]

I cant help but think this is probably something trivial but am at my wits end at the same time. Any advice is welcome.

Again, i want to import the ace editor from `ace-builds`. Since it has worked before, and other requires dont work either, i guess it is something different. I am using Webpack - maybe theres the problem? I can give more info if needed.

Edit:

at index.js of knoala:

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: '.',
    paths: {
        ace: 'node_modules/ace-builds/src', ...
```

Comment: I don't see `ace` in the tree.

Comment: @lilezek that was changed at the index.js see my edit.

Comment: What is your webpack config?